# How to measure cpu time of TCL script

Tags: scripting, tcl, performance-testing, cpu-time

I have long TCL script . I want measure exact cpu time the process is taking in TCL

I tried the time command in TCL but I am not sure it is correct way to measure cpu time taken by complete TCL script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tcl itself doesn't provide this information. You want to use the TclX package's `times` command.

```
package require Tclx

set pre [times]
# do CPU intensive operation here; for example calculating the length of a number with many digits...
string length [expr {13**12345}]
set post [times]

# the current process's non-OS CPU time is the first element; it's in milliseconds
set cpuSecondsTaken [expr {([lindex $post 0] - [lindex $pre 0]) / 1000.0}]
# The other elements are: system-cpu-time, subprocess-user-cpu-time, subprocess-system-time
```

You are, of course, dependent on the OS measuring this information correctly. It's not portable to non-POSIX systems (e.g., Windows) though there might be something logically similar in the TWAPI package.

Comment: Sometimes it is easier to just use the shell command `time` to wrap a call to Tcl. That works fine enough for crude measurements.